# Is there a command line music client?

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command line audio players](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44443/command-line-audio-players)

I want a command line music player which can play all formats including mp3,ogg.
Also i want it should have the features like pause,play,stop.
That means basic music player is enough for me.
IS there anything available for ubuntu?