# How do you play a sound from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, sound

I'm wondering if there's a command I can install to play an audio file from the terminal, or if I can do it with Python or a different code?  I just want to type a command, have it play a sound until the sound is finished, then return to the prompt.  I don't want a GUI.

Comment: Looking at the answers under https://askubuntu.com/questions/44443/command-line-audio-players this doesn't seem like a duplicate. The `sox` solution under here is not present under the linked question, and that is the answer: here, but not there.

Comment: nvlc doesn't just return to a prompt (although the hotkeys for volume are handier than my next suggestion). mpv --no-audio-display will play in the terminal and return to a prompt when it's done playing. If you specify a folder instead of a file, it will play all the songs in the folder.

Comment: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: use aplay command

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes you can do it with many commandline tools like `mpg123`, `aplay` , `cvlc` and `mplayer`, but I suggest the `play` command. To install it:

```
sudo apt install sox
```

And for playing special formats like `mp3` you must install its libraries:

```
sudo apt install libsox-fmt-mp3
```

And to use it:

```
play music.mp3
```

If you want to use it with full libraries, you must install `libsox-fmt-all` package:

```
sudo apt install libsox-fmt-all
```

Comment: When I run `play` on a short bell sound, it tends to only play part of the sound, for some reason. Didn't occur when I used `mpg123`.

Comment: Also `paplay` which is installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with another tool called mpg123, to install it,

```
sudo apt install mpg123
```

and then use it by,

```
mpg123 file.mp3
```

Comment: `mpg123` worked better for me than `play`, see above.

Comment: `mpg123` is not able to play a file such as: `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga`. Instead, `paplay` can do that.

Answer (score 0):

paplay was a better answer for me as it had the most comprehensible and stable (doesn't change on reboot) method for choosing a sound device. And it is installed by default.

To see devices for it, do

```
pactl list | grep Name
```

I'm not sure this will 100% be the case, but usually the ones you want will contain the word "output" and will not contain the word "monitor" (which is a virtual input device created from an output device).

In my case, the one I'm using is my HDMI screen, called "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo". Find the one you want, and then you'll end up with a command like:

```
paplay --d="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo" filename.ogg
```